# Vuetify Dark theme stored in cookie and localStorage not available in Nuxt SSR in created() hook and i see blink between light and dark theme

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

I have this peace of code in my **default.vue** layout

```
        beforeCreate() {
          console.warn('Cookie val=' + Cookies.get('dte'));
          console.warn('Cookie val is for dark: ' + (Cookies.get('dte') === 'true'));
          var userDarkThemeEnabled = this.$store.getters.isDarkThemeEnabledUser;
          console.warn('created userDarkThemeEnabled:' + userDarkThemeEnabled);
          if (userDarkThemeEnabled == null) {
            this.goDark = false;
            return;
          }
          this.goDark = userDarkThemeEnabled;
      },
```

in console i see

```
    **Nuxt SSR**

     Cookie val=undefined

     Cookie val is for dark: false
     created userDarkThemeEnabled: false

    **Client Side**

     Cookie val=true
     Cookie val is for dark: true
     created userDarkThemeEnabled: true
```

Because this beforeCreate hook calls twice for SSR and client side when page reloads i got some blink for color theme in Vuetify, because variable goDark for SSR took value false and vuetify applies light theme, and then goDark became true and vuetify change theme to dark.

If i hardcode value like this.goDark=true, it will be applied for SSR and for client side during page reload.
So my question is there any way to get value stored for anonymous user(who is not logged in yet but already changed theme) in SSR?

Answer (score 1):

So looks like i found solutions. In created hook i can access Server side cookie through

```
this.$nuxt.context.req.headers.cookie
```

Checked what i have in console:

```
SSR                                                                                                                                           
auth.strategy=local; auth.redirect=%2Fcontacts; dte=true
```

So you can find piece of code which works for me

```
    initTheme() {
      let themeEnabled;
      if (process.server) {
        themeEnabled = this.$parseCookies(this.$nuxt.context.req)['theme'] === 'true';
      } else {
        themeEnabled = this.$store.getters.IS_DARK_THEME_ENABLED;
      }
      this.goDark = themeEnabled;  // use this for  <v-app :dark="isDarkTheme"> computed property isDarkTheme see below
      this.$setTheme(themeEnabled); // store in vuex
    }
 isDarkTheme() {return this.$vuetify.theme.dark = this.goDark;}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm trying to do the same thing. Have the user only see the dark theme if that's their preference.

Comment: @Mellson yes, inside vue lifecycle hook you can access cookie through this.$nuxt.context.req.headers.cookie and then you can initialize theme using value stored in cookie. In this case if you will set value to theme during SSR you will not see any blinking